# Parse-Server source _rperm and _wperm mongo queries, and should I index them?

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

I'm going through my mongo logs to add indexes for my unindexed queries. By default, mongo only logs queries that take over 100ms to complete.

I've found that I have several on _wperm and _rperm keys. I see that is how the ACL gets broken down. But what type of Parse.Query call might create a query like this in the logs?

`query: { orderby: {}, $query: { _rperm: { $in: [ null, "*", "[UserId]" ] } } }`

I'm even noticing that this query is on a class that has only 8 total objects, yet is taking 133ms to complete, which seems really slow for such a small class, even if it had to do an in memory sort and scan.

Should I solve this at the code level, modifying my query to avoid this type of mongo query? Or should I add an index for these types of queries?

I notice I also have a few that are showing up in the Slow Queries tab on mLab.  The query looks like `{"_id":"<val>","_wperm":{"$in":["<vals>"]}}`, with the suggested index `{"_id": 1, "_wperm": 1}`, but it has the following note:

> "_id" is in the existing {"_id": 1} unique index. The following index recommendation should only be necessary in certain circumstances.

Yet, this is one of my slower queries, taking 320 ms to complete. It's on the _User class. Is that just because the _User class has a lot of rows? Since the _id is unique I feel like it shouldn't really make a difference adding a _wperm index, since I end up with only a single object.

I'm curious if I will see a benefit from taking action on these queries or if I should safely ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should index your collections following the mongodb recommendations. In the good old parse.com days, those indexes were created automatically based on the seen workloads. Now you need to create them. Both make sense. The _rperm will be hit on every queries run without a masterKey. The _wperm in every write. In the future, we could automatically create the _id + _wperm index as all writes use this index

Comment: That makes sense what causes the queries. How does an index for `{"_id":1, "_wperm":1}` provide extra benefit though, especially when it's a query with the _id field already? Is this always going to be slow, or only if we have complex ACL set ups with tons of roles and individual users? So, `{"_id":1, "_wperm":1}` may as well be set on every class, but I only really need to worry about an "_rperm" index on queries that show up in the mLab slow queries tab, right?

Comment: You got it! the index on both _id / _wperm will still provide extra benefit as you'll save CPU cycles writing to your data as it won't need to read from the DB to make sure the _wperm matches the contents of your update. Also on _rperm, check your slow queries and optimize from there.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry, I've only recently really started putting on my DB Administrator hat, and wanna make sure I get this. So, indexes are kept in memory when possible. A write doesn't strictly require pulling data out of storage, only putting it in. However, since we have permissions, we need to know that we pass those permissions. Without the _wperm index, we need to load the object from storage in order to check if we pass the permission check, whereas the index would enable us to know off the bat if we're able to update the data based on info in memory instead of having to load anything.

Comment: Acutally, Mongo itself isn't enforcing these permissions right? This is actually a feature of Parse-Server? So if we're not performing a master key save, it first needs to check permissions, which still can utilize an in-memory index if the _id, _wperm index is created. I guess that also explains why we don't have a way to build our own mongo queries through Parse.Query, as we could add the '*' _rperm / _wperm ourselves.

Comment: You are 100% right. Also adding the index on _id/_wperm should be something the server does on it’s own as all writes done by users will be using this index. It’s better to have it early than when you have millions of objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I just realized, though, my first query is doing this: `{ _rperm: { $in: [ null, "*", "[UserId]" ] } }`  Since `*` is included there, doesn't that mean the master key is being used and this query is unnecessary? I might be wrong, as again I'm just trying to figure this stuff out more, but it looks like if a user session is ever used it will perform the query regardless of the master key also being used. Or I suppose *a* query needs to be performed, but it doesn't need to be burdened by also querying against the _rperm key.

Comment: ‘*’ indicate and explicit public read access on the object. So for a user to be able to read an object it needs either: no ACL (null), explicit public read (‘*’), or user read (‘[userId]’)